# Can we use jQuery UI autocomplete for populating an existing select box?

Tags: jquery-ui, select, autocomplete, filtering

Is there a way of using [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) autocomplete not to open a suggestion pulldown but populating an existing select box?

A similar workaround can be done with

http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/filterlist/

or

http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/narrowing/

But can we use jQuery UI?

Comment: Your example links looks like simple filters, not autocompletes.

Comment: No they are filtering as we type but what i want is the reverse functionality... a textbox for typing in and a select box (empty at first) filled by autocomplete plugin. Simply , instead of opening a suggestion list , filling existing select box with results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I've figured this out after many hours. After redigging autocomplete's data bind as Bouillou redirected me I did these to achieve my goal.

1. First, I replaced the search function by adding mine for adding a line for cleaning all previous select box contents. Here is my new search function:

   ```
        search: function( event, ui ){
            $("#links_list option").remove(); // This line is added
            var str = '';
            for(var attr in event){
                str += attr.toString() + '\n';
            }
            console.log(str);

            var str2 = '';
            for(var attr in ui){
                str2 += attr.toString() + '\n';
            }
            console.log(str2);
        },
   ```
2. I then tweaked `.data` binding and `_renderItem`. `return $('');` is breaking the process and only returns one suggestion with a null suggestion box. (Which I don't want to see either.)

Then I changed the original `return(.....)` in `_renderItem` function to this:

```
        return $('<option value="'+item.value+'">'+item.label+'</option>')
        .appendTo("#links_list");
```

You can see a sample screen result below.

[image: And the result]

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve the filtered data using the renderer and do whatever you want with them

```
$('#myAutocomplete').data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    $('#myCustomElement').append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )

    //Cancel the suggestion rendering
    //return void since 1.9 else just return false
    return $('');
};
```

Inspired by http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

**EDIT**

Add fiddle explaining how avoid suggestion list : http://jsfiddle.net/GF5c4/

Comment: thanks for your answer i did read that before and tried to implement but cannot prevent the suggestion box opening and latter functionalities. Indeed i just need a filled select box :select and other functions shoudnt be active.

Comment: Even if you return $('')? As it removes suggestion, if you do that for all filtered suggestions, you don't have anything displayed, do you?

Comment: not opening the jsfiddle page but i got the clue is _renderItem called once for each result  ... starting to try thay way thanks again :)

Comment: no way just getting the first item and breaks also showing a null suggextion box with a lower height ... i will try something else ...

Comment: upvoted for clue but i can not accept as answer because  return $(''); was not the right way to do this...

Comment: Do you know the right way to avoid displaying the result without return $('')?